I cannot get all data to export to CSV
# Collect batting stats for the 2022, 2023, and 2024 seasons
try:
    print("Collecting batting stats from 2022 to 2024...")
    batting_data = batting_stats(2021, 2024, league="all", ind=1 )
    
    # Save the collected data to a CSV file
    batting_data.to_csv('batting_stats_2021_2024.csv', index=False)
    print("Batting data collection complete. File saved as 'batting_stats_2022_2024.csv'.")

except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

I am trying to use pybaseball to pull this data.
It made a csv, but it only contains 526 rows of data, only a few players from each team.
Why am I not getting all of the data? Thanks

How can we possibly tell?  Where did the data come from?  How many rows are in batting_data?

@Chad At the very least, we have to have some idea of what the batting_stats function does.

Just a wild guess. but is this pybaseball? If so you really need to include that in your question. Perhaps showing your imports when asking this question would help.

Is there everything in batting_data ? the problem may come from the collecting function.

Sorry, first time using slack overflow, it is from pybaseball, it should come up with way more rows, but it is not.  I apologize for confusion, and thank you for any and all input!!

All we can say is that there is some mistake in the batting_stats() function, or a mistake in how you are calling it.  But you have not shown us that function, so how can we possibly say what the exact cause is?

Try passing qual=0 per this post pitching_stats and batting_stats not returning all data

@JonSG  I will try that, thank you.

@JonSG you legend, that worked.  Thank you so much.  How do I mark this question as 'Solved' or something similar?

Normally, a question is "answered" and one would mark an answer as "accepted" but we have just been chatting in comments. I'm not sure my comment rises to the level of an answer though.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
